# Should I transfer my photos via Samsung Smart Switch, when I sync them via Google Photos anyway?

Tags: samsung, data-transfer, google-photos, samsung-smart-switch

I sync my photos (and videos) via Google Photos on my old Android device (Sony Xperia) and I plan to continue using Google Photos with the same Google account on my new Samsung Galaxy phone.

When I set up my new Samsung Galaxy phone I want to transfer all my data from my old Sony phone to the new Samsung phone.

Will I get duplicates if I simply transfer all data including images (and videos) via Samsung Smart Switch from the old to the new phone, once I sync my new phone with my Google account?

(Also for WhatsApp I want to restore my chat history including photos from my Google Drive Backup, while the WhatsApp photos are also synced via Google Photos. Will this result in duplicates?)

Are these duplicates resolved automatically or what is the best solution to avoid duplicates?